# Make Overlay did clickable in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using a jquery script called capSlide on the following page

http://sundial.whistlerwebhosting.com/meetings-events/whistler-weddings

When a user mouses over the image a transparent overlay appears on top and a caption slides up with a title and a more info link.

I want to make the entire div area clickable. I am thinking that since the overlay appears on top its this div that I need to make active with the link. I am trying to use the following jquery script but it is not working.

```
jQuery('.overlay').click(function(){
     window.location=jQuery(this).parent().find('a').attr('href'); 
       return false;
});
```

The HTML output is as follows

```
<div class="ic_wrapper">
   <div id="capslide_img_cont11" class="ic_container"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="/sites/all/themes/sundial/images/weddings/Wedding-Consulants.jpg" width="290" height="180" alt="Whistler Wedding Consulants" />
    <div class="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="ic_caption">
      <h3>Wedding Consulants</h3>
      <a href="/meetings-events/whistler-weddings/wedding-planners">
      <p class="ic_text">More Info</p>
       </a> </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

any insight would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your click event isn't being registered because the overlay div is added after your script runs. Try using the `on()` or `delegate()` jQuery functions. An example:

```
 jQuery(".ic_container").on("click", ".overlay", function(){
        window.location = jQuery(this).parent().find('a').attr('href'); 
        return false;
 });
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I have tired this but still no joy. Is the use of .parent still correct in your example above. The actual href is located withing the .ic_container div not it's parent. Or is this pointing referance from the .overlay perspective.

Comment: the value `this` in my example refers to the `.overlay` selector

Answer (score 0):

In your script file (functions.js), you are setting your click handler outside your document ready function. Instead, put it **inside** your ready function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div#block-menu-menu-meeting-events-right.block div.content ul.menu li.last a').addClass('fancybox.iframe');

    // Your code has been moved to here...
    jQuery('.overlay').click(function(){
        window.location=jQuery(this).parent().children().find('a').attr('href'); 
        return false;
    });    
});
```

This makes it wait until the page is ready before applying your click handler.